# How to install discourse forum along with multiple sites via varnish & hitch proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, varnish, discourse

I'm using virtualmin with apache for my other sites.

apache listening one port 8080
varnish port 80
hitch port 443
discourse port 8081

With below **default.vcl** file, there isn't any problem with my other apache sites.
Although discourse site opens, but with lot of problems.

- logo not appearing, attachments not working.

I tried to turn on force https option in admin panel of discourse, but with this, no user can login to site.

**My varnish config:**

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "192.168.1.103";
    .port = "8080";
}
backend discourse {
    .host = "192.168.1.103";
    .port = "8081";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.http.host == "discourse.example.com") {
        set req.backend_hint = discourse;
        return (pipe);
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;

    }

    if (std.port(server.ip) != 443) {
set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
return(synth(301));
}

    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        }
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    # Happens after we have read the response headers from the backend.
    #
    # Here you clean the response headers, removing silly Set-Cookie headers
    # and other mistakes your backend does.
}

sub vcl_synth {

    if (resp.status == 301 || resp.status == 302) {
        set resp.http.location = req.http.location;
        return (deliver);
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    # Happens when we have all the pieces we need, and are about to send the
    # response to the client.
    #
    # You can do accounting or modifying the final object here.
}
```

**My changes in discourse app.yml:**

```
expose: 
- "8081:80" # http
# - "443:443" # https

## Uncomment these two lines if you wish to add Lets Encrypt (https)
# - "templates/web.ssl.template.yml"
# - "templates/web.letsencrypt.ssl.template.yml"
## If you added the Lets Encrypt template, uncomment below to get a free SSL certificate
# LETSENCRYPT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL: me@example.com
```

**My hitch config changes:**

```
pem-file = "/home/discourse/ssl.everything"
```

Help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

hum...

My first guess would be on your discourse configuration. I don't know that software, but if your errors are something like HTTP 404 on logo and attachment, could be a wrong discourse configuration.
Could be resolved either

- setting a x-forwared-host header, with something like the code below in the vcl_recv

  set req.http.x-forwarded-host = req.http.host;
- hardcoding the discours hostname into discourse configuration, like the following configuration might suggest: https://github.com/discourse/discourse_docker/blob/c4ff0d122ecc705badf707880bd3c696121866ae/samples/web_only.yml#L44

some things about your vcl..  it's really confused

- the return(pipe) call makes your whole website not cacheable.. if you don't need cache, why are you using varnish (and not something easier to handle like a nginx or an apache httpd configuration)
- your vcl_backend_response, vcl_synth and vcl_deliver declaration are unnecessary
- you're using return(pipe) before redirecting to the https in case of http.. so the redirect won't work for your discourse website.
- But theoretically the second proto might be http in your case ..

  ```
   if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
       set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
   } else {
       set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
   }
  ```

At the end, the following code should probably be a enought and sufficient working configuration for you

```
vcl 4.1;
import std;
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "192.168.1.103";
    .port = "8080";
}
# Discours backend declaration
backend discourse {
    .host = "192.168.1.103";
    .port = "8081";
}

sub vcl_recv {


    if (std.port(server.ip) != 443) {
         set req.http.location = "https://" + req.http.host + req.url;
         return(synth(301));
    }

    if (!req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        if(std.port(server.ip) == 443) {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "https";
        } else {
            set req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto = "http";
        }
    }
    if (req.http.host == "discourse.example.com") {
        # Telling discourse the website is discourse.example.com
        # might be sufficient (if not, hardcode your website hostname into discourse
        set req.http.x-forwarded-host = req.http.host;
        set req.backend_hint = discourse;
        # Do you really want a pipe
        # (i.e. pathing the request to discourse without any transformation/cache? )
        return (pipe);
    } else {
        set req.backend_hint = default;
    }
}
```